# Memory leak after deleting pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a memory leak and I have no idea why it happens. Please note, I removed most of the code that has nothing to do with the issue and most of it was given in the assignment, so I only wrote the `Tetrahedron` and the `add_triangles(...)` function:

```
class Geometry {
protected:
    unsigned int vao, vbo;
public:
    /* Generates 1 vertex buffer */
};

class Tetrahedron : public Geometry {
    std::vector<VertexData> vtxData;
    vec3 points[4];
public:
    Tetrahedron() : points { /* default points */ } { create(); }
    Tetrahedron(const vec3 p0, const vec3 p1, const vec3 p2, const vec3 p3) : points { p0, p1, p2, p3 } { create(); }
    void create() {
        /* Creates the 4 sides ans stores at vtxData */
        /* Passing the data to OpenGL */
    }
    void gen(std::vector<Tetrahedron*>& data, int stop_at = 0, float tend = 1, int depth = 0) {
        data.push_back(this);
        if (depth > stop_at) {
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            /* calculate new points */
            (new Tetrahedron{ /* new points */ })->gen(data, stop_at, tend, depth + 1);
        }
    }
};

struct Object {
    Geometry* geometry;
public:
    /* Drawns and rotates the given geometry */
};

class Scene {
    std::vector<Object*> objects;
    std::vector<Tetrahedron*> thets;
public:
    void Build() {
        /* Setting up shaders, lights, materials, objects */
        add_triangles();
    }
    void add_triangles(float tend = 1) {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
            delete objects[i];
        } std::vector<Object*>{}.swap(objects);

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < thets.size(); i++) {
            delete thets[i];
        } std::vector<Tetrahedron*>{}.swap(thets);

        (new Tetrahedron{})->gen(thets, 1, tend);

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < thets.size(); i++) {
            objects.push_back(new Object{ thets[i] });
        }
    }
    void Animate(float tstart, float tend) {
        /* ... */
        add_triangles(fabs(cosf(tend) * sinf(tend)) + 1);
        /* ... */
    }
    ~Scene() {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
            delete objects[i];
        }
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < thets.size(); i++) {
            delete thets[i];
        }
    }
};
```

For some reason the memory leak occurs when I don't store the Tetrahedrons in a separated vector and just deletes them in the Object's destructor:

```
~Object() { delete geometry; }
```

Why does it leak if it should be the same as deleting them in the for loop written in the `add_triangles(...)` function? - I used VS2019 to compile it.

To correct myself:

- This code infact, does not leak, it deletes the Tetrahedrons individually.
- If I want the Object to delete its Tetrahedron "geometry", it leaks.

Comment: "`new Tetrahedron`" -- can you explain where you expect all of ***these*** objects to be `delete`d? After all, since you just `new`ed this object, it has to be `delete`d at some point, to avoid leaking this memory, right? And what exactly is "`std::vector<Tetrahedron*>{}.swap(thets);`" is all about? What's that supposed to do? This doesn't do anything at all. It appears you are missing a detail, or two, about how C++ objects work, and dynamic scope, on a fundamental level.

Comment: *"I removed most of the code that has nothing to do with the issue..."* I have a hunch about where the bug is.

Comment: I expect all of these objects to be deleted at each add_triangles call and in the destructor. std::vector<Tetrahedron*>{}.swap(thets); is to clear the vector.

Comment: Don't use owning bare pointers.

Comment: @Beta there is no pointer allocation elsewhere.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, The empty swap is what `shrink_to_fit` replaced.

Comment: why do you store pointers? `std::vector<Tetrahedron*> thets;` could be a `std::vector<Tetrahedron> thets;`

Comment: How do you "expect all of these objects to be deleted" when the pointer that gets `new`ed is completely discarded, lost forever, thus leaking it forever? Just because you `new`ed something in a class method doesn't mean that whatever gets `new`ed will get automatically deleted when the class gets destroyed. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Try replacing all of your pointers with either unique_ptr or shared_ptr and replace all "new" calls with make_unique or make_shared.

Comment: SamVarshavchik "delete objects[i];" and  "delete thets[i];", these are called.
@ZanLynx It would wok, but unfortunately I including memory is prohibited in this assignment.

Comment: It's great that "`"delete objects[i];" and "delete thets[i];", these are called`". Now, can you explain exactly which part of the code that all these `new Tetrahedron`s and places them in either of these vectors? Just because the code is deleting some `Tetrahedron` pointers, somewhere, doesn't mean that every `new Tetrahedron` will get deleted. Again: C++ does not work this way. I already explained to you that all of these `new Tetrahedron`s are what's leaking memory, because they never get deleted. I can't explain it any simpler. That's your memory leak.

Comment: void gen: data.push_back(this);
All of the pointers gets stored in the vector.

Comment: *"For some reason the memory leak occurs when I don't store the Tetrahedrons in a separated vector and just deletes them in the Object's destructor"* You seem to be saying that the code you've shown does not in fact leak, but instead some hypothetical code that you haven't shown but only described in prose does leak. Show the code that doesn't work, not the code that works. Prepare a [mcve].

Comment: You seem to believe that `std::vector<Tetrahedron*>` should automatically call `delete` on the pointers it holds when it's destroyed or cleared. If so, you believe incorrectly; it should not, and does not. If that's the behavior you want, `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Tetrahedron>>` is likely what you are looking for.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik no, my problem is: If I write a destructor for the Object to destroy it's geometry, it starts leaking. If I delete the Tetrahedrons afterwards I destroyed the Objects, it does not leak, but both of them should be the same in theory.

Comment: If you *HAVE TO* use raw pointers then don't forget the Rule of 3 (or 5). You must provide the constructor, destructor, copy and assignment (these count as one for some reason), then after C++11 you need the move constructor and move assignment (but only if you want them). If you *don't want* objects to be copied then mark the copy constructor and assignment operators as "deleted." Also read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: As @CedricR points out in their answer, `delete geometry` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of calling `delete` on a pointer of a type that a) is not the object's dynamic type, and b) has a non-virtual destructor.

Comment: Oh yeah virtual objects. Get in the habit of marking classes as "final" or give them a virtual destructor, even if it is `virtual ~Class() = default;`

Comment: So the bug was in the code the OP didn't post. Who knew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tetrahedron inherits from Geometry and you are deleting from a pointer to a Geometry object.
The destructor of Tetrahedron is not called because you did not define the destructor of Geometry as virtual.

Add a virtual destructor to Geometry to allow the destructor of Tetrahedron to be called in this case.

```
class Geometry {
protected:
    // ...
public:
    virtual ~Geometry() {} // <= Virtual destructor
};
```

Comment: How do you expect that doing this will solve all the memory leaks from `new`ed objects that never get `delete`d?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik There are no newed objects that are never deleted; or at least, it's not immediately obvious there are. The pattern is `(new Tetrahedron{})->gen(thets, 1, tend);`, and the important point is that `gen` does `thets.push_back(this)` first thing.

Comment: Actually the code is really not readable and should be rewritten totally but the gen function is called on the newed object and it push this to the "data" vector (which is thets).